# Issue in getting subtree in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I am stuck in coding where I have to get subtree for a given node in SML.

The data type is below.

```
datatype ctree = Empty | Node of char*ctree*ctree
```

Now I have to write function which will return subtree rooted at a given node.

I wrote a helper function 'nodeExist(n,tree)' which will check if the node exists on the tree.Then I tried some sort of below-

```
fun getSubtree(x,ctree) =
   case ctree of
         Empty => Empty
      | Node(y,left,right) => if(nodeExist (x,ctree)) = true then Node(x,left,right) else Empty;
```

It is not giving proper output.Can Node(x,left,right) give the subtree,or I should traverse the tree properly to get it.

Comment: `Node (x,left,right)` is the same tree as `ctree`, but with its root element replaced by `x`. You need to traverse the tree. (And you don't need `nodeExist`.)

Comment: Thanks.I fixed this using nodeExist, but somehow not able to do without it.I want to do something like fun subtree(x,Empty) = Empty
   | subtree(x,T as Node(y,left,right)) =
     if (x=y) then T
     else subtree(x,left) orelse subtree(x,right);  But orelse is giving type mismatch error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will start with your attempt from the comments, as it's very close:

```
fun subtree(x, Empty) = Empty 
  | subtree(x, T as Node(y, left, right)) = 
        if x = y 
        then T 
        else subtree(x, left) orelse subtree(x, right)
```

but it has a type problem since `orelse` wants two truth values, not two trees.
You need to do something logically similar, but with trees instead of facts.

One way to see a path forward is to rewrite the `orelse` as the equivalent case analysis

```
fun subtree(x, Empty) = Empty 
  | subtree(x, T as Node(y, left, right)) = 
        if x = y 
        then T 
        else let val l = subtree(x, left) in
             case l of
                 true => l
               | false => subtree(x, right)
             end
```

From here, we can just replace the boolean cases with tree cases:

```
fun subtree(x, Empty) = Empty 
  | subtree(x, T as Node(y, left, right)) = 
        if x = y 
        then T 
        else let val l = subtree(x, left) in
             case l of
                 Node _ => l
               | Empty  => subtree(x, right)
             end
```

or, it could be rearranged a little to make it shorter

```
fun subtree(x, Empty) = Empty 
  | subtree(x, T as Node(y, left, right)) = 
        if x = y 
        then T 
        else case subtree(x, left) of
               Empty  => subtree(x, right)
             | t => t
```

(This is a pretty roundabout way to find a solution, but it's how my train of thought went as I tried to rework your function.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.